# php loop that creates directories using numbers that count up within 4 character spots

Tags: php, loops, mkdir

I have a php loop and I have the code that creates a directory...

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 925; $i++){


    if (!file_exists('C:\wamp\www\maindirectory\mydirectory\0001')) {
        mkdir('C:\wamp\www\maindirectory\mydirectory\0001', 0777, true);
    }
}

?>
```

Obviously this code will not work. However, where 0001 is in the above code, I need it to count up as 0001, 0002, 0003, etc. The last directory would be 0925. How can I do this?

Comment: Whats this line all about `";` I would guess if you removed that the script might compile and run

Comment: Look into [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: Or [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly or even just `str_repeat( '0', 4 - strlen( $i ) ).$i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sprintf` => http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

In your case:

```
mkdir('C:/wamp/www/maindirectory/mydirectory/' . sprintf("%04d", $i), 0777, true);
```

I think you will manage to finish the code.